# Date Modified isn't updated while StreamWriter is open

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, streamwriter

I have a logging solution and write to a textfile which is open when aplication is running. I use StreamWriter to write to file. My logger code is simply (to open stream and to write):

```
public void Open(string filePath, bool append)
    {
        if (this.logWriter != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Logger is already open");

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

        this.logWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        this.logWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    }

public void CreateEntry(string entry)
    {
        if (this.logWriter == null)
            return;

        this.logWriter.WriteLine(entry);

    }
```

Problem is that while writing to file, entries are written, file size is changing, but "Date Modified" attribute doesn't change. Any thoughts? How can I manually update modify date?

PS: I am on Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

The modified date returned by `FindNextFile` is the cached value stored in the directory entry, not the always updated value stored in the MFT record (inode equivalent). This is for performance reasons, so the information for a whole directory can be obtained with a single read, rather than a read for each file.

It is updated whenever an handle to the file is closed.*

You can always get up-to-date information by using `GetFileInformationByHandle` or `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`. To use this function you should open the file using `CreateFile`, while requesting neither read nor write access and allowing sharing.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_T("Path/To/File"), 
    0, // No read or write access needed
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, // Don't create 
    0, NULL);
```

This handle can then be used with `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`.

Alternatively simply closing this handle will update the directory entry to reflect the current values.

*(To be accurate, whenever a handle which was opened through that name is closed, since a file can have multiple hard links.)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation